# How to embed a Bing Map

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I am working in a application that is using Bing (AJAX) to generate a map object to a webpage.

In addition to creating the map, we are using the API to add pushpins and create polygons that we color to highlight an area on the map.

What I would like to do is to be able to embed that final map into another document such as word or powerpoint.

Once I have a generated map how can I go about embedding it? In my markup I don't an "img" tag.

Comment: just take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good solution to this. As I mentioned on the MSND forums one of the many HTML 2 canvas libraries may be an option. The one you tried didn't seem to work. I have made a code sample that does what you need but it is really complicated and requires rendering the image server side. If you email me as I mentioned in my MSDN response I'll email you a copy of the project. In the future there will likely be a better option for this.

Comment: Is it possible to create a static map with a colored polygon(s) using Rest API?

Comment: No. The REST API's currently do not support rendering polygons on static images.

Comment: Could I create a static map using the REST API to highlight (an x amount) of locations? For example highlight 5 US state counties on a map.

Comment: No, the API only provides the option to highlight a single location at a time. It is possible to draw polygons on top of the map image in your code. This requires using System.Drawing, or the HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: Does Bing offer something that I can entirely do server side? I would scrap the Bing AJAX, generate an image server side and pass it to the webpage?  The server side option would have to handle large amounts of polygon points.

Comment: There is the Bing Maps REST imagery service, but it doesn't support polygons. As I mentioned in the MSDN forums, I have a code sample that generates an image server side and supports polygons. It use the AJAX control as the front end, but you could skip that and simply pass in a JSON object that matches the schema used in that code sample.

Comment: I did try to use that sample.  It does accomplish the task, however I get instances where tiles come up missing on the rendered image.  It's happening too frequently for me to move forward with.

Comment: I came across someone who got html2canvas to work, but it uses CORS which Bing doesnt support.